# Удаление объекта из json файла (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

Не могу решить эту проблему уже несколько дней. У меня есть файл profile.json, в который записываются уровень участника канала в дискорде, накопленный опыт, коины и т.д. При бане пользователя данные с profile.json о его прогрессе на канале должны быть стёрты (объект должен быть удалён). Но почему-то код, представленный ниже работает не совсем так. Это тестовая команда бота, с помощью которой я и решил проверить данную функцию:

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.channel.send('pong!');
    let profile = require('../profile.json');
    delete profile['2292341016223744'];
    if (profile == null)
      profile = '{}';
    fs.writeFile('./profile.json', JSON.stringify(profile, null, ' '), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ping"
};
```

Сам файл profile.json до выполнения этой команды:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не очень понимаю почему именно такой результат. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет, может я где-то допустил ошибку в коде.

P.S. Насчёт расположения файлов: все команды, включая ту, код которой был приведён выше, лежат в отдельной папке cmds, сам бот находится в корневой папке так же, как и profile.json.

Comment: Попробуй заменить require на fs.readFile + JSON.parse. Впрочем, я совершенно не понимаю, как подобный код может испортить json, потому что очевидно, что записывается корректный json. И ещё, поздно проверять переменную на null, если ты уже обращался к её полю.

Comment: А ни чо так считывает в ../profile.json а записываешь в ./profile.json ../ и ./

Comment: @AzizUmarov, если там будет ../ - он попросту создаст новый файл на рабочем столе)

Comment: @Qwertiy let profile = JSON.parse(fs.readFile('../profile.json', (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }));
таким образом?

Comment: Ясно вопрос снят. Главное что ты в курсе куда смотреть

Comment: @AzizUmarov, я понимаю, это непривычно, но почему-то в функции работает именно так)

Comment: @vanyavanya, конечно нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можете показать как правильно?

Comment: В `require` относительный путь считается от директории в которой расположен скрипт с `require`, а в `fs.readFile`/`fs.writeFile` относительно текущей рабочей директории. Чаще всего это разные директории. И вообще использовать `require` не для скриптов/конфигов это плохая идея. В частности потому что он кешируется.

Comment: О, а ещё идея читать и писать в файл асинхронно в боте это так себе идея. Используйте нормальную базу данных

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а разве с наличием БД что-то поменяется?

Comment: Ну там хотя бы есть транзакционность и гарантии целостности данных

Comment: @AlexeyTen, и какую базу данных вы можете предложить?

Comment: @Qwertiy, let temp = fs.readFileSync('./profile.json');
let profile = JSON.parse(temp);
Ошибка: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

Comment: @vanyavanya, ну так json исправь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, он исправлен.

Comment: @vanyavanya, Кодировку укажи, BOM удали, подебажь.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Firebase подойдёт?